# Autocomplete of xml tags in VSCode based on xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, visual-studio-code

Does VSCode implement some kind of autocomplete based on XML schema like standard Visual Studio does?
If not, is there an extension that implements that feature?

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/tsvetan-ganev/nativescript-vscode-snippets) extension. It's sufficient for my purposes. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 3):

They don't have any in-house xml completion tool unfortunately.

Please use this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Comment: This extension supports only autoclose tag but not xml completion based on xsd

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml  which provides [xml completion based on xsd](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/blob/main/docs/Features/XMLFeatures.md#completion-based-on-xsd)

vscode-xml provide too xml validation based on xsd, jump to the declared xsd element from the xml element, provides too à support to editing xsd like xsd validation for xsd file.

To know the all supported features, I suggest that you read [Users guide](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/blob/main/docs/Features/XMLFeatures.md)